# YouTube brand account or not

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel

I'm trying to create a brand account and a channel that's attached to it.

I created a new channel but it didn't ask me to create a brand account in the process. How do I know if this channel is a brand account channel or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created the channel via https://www.youtube.com/channel_switcher, it definitely is connected to a brand account. If your channel is connected to a brand account, you'll see an option to add managers on https://www.youtube.com/account, and a "you are the owner of this channel and brand account" on https://www.youtube.com/account_advanced.